# Error sending data to php with ajax in wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have this form:

```
<select id="mudar_produto">
    <option></option> 
    <option value="#produto_1">Novo Produto Higiene</option> 
</select>
<section class="hide-section" id="produto_1"> 
<form class="form-validate" id="feedback_form">
    <div class="campo">
        <fieldset> 
            <h1>
                <legend>
                    <center>
                        <strong>Produtos de Higiene</strong>
            </center>
        </h1><br> 
        </div>
        <fieldset class="grupo">
    <div class="campo">
            <strong><label for="Nome do Produto">Nome do Produto</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoProd" name="DescricaoProd" required="" style="width:350px">
        </div>
    <div class="campo"> 
        <strong><label for="Unidade">Unidade</label></strong> 
            <input type="text" id="DescricaoUnid" name="DescricaoUnid" style="width:160px" required="" size="120">
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn_contact" type="button">Registo</button>
</form>
</section>
```

I have this ajax to send the data without refresh to the page and clean the inputs:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(".btn_contact").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "inserir",
                    data: $("#feedback_form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        if ($.trim(data) == 'true') {
                            $("#feedback_form").find('input').val(''); //clear text
                            $(".success_messages").removeClass('hide'); // success message
                        } else {
                            $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
</script>
```

On the insert page I have the php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "xxx.xxx.x.xx"; 
$username = "xxxxxx"; 
$password = "xxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbname = "xxxxxxxx"; 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
$conn->set_charset('utf8');
$name = isset($_POST["DescricaoProd"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoProd"] : '';
$unid = isset($_POST["DescricaoUnid"]) ? $_POST["DescricaoUnid"] : '';
if (!empty($name)) && (!empty($unid)) { 

    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}    

$sql = "INSERT INTO ProdHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

$conn->close(); 

?>
```

But when I click the register button I get the following error in the console:

> POST http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/wordpress/index.php/inserir 500 (Internal
>   Server Error)

and does not insert into the database table.

In addition to the error that @Jeff identified had this syntax error:

```
if (!empty ($name)) && (!empty ($unid)) {
```

I had to switch to:

```
if (!empty ($name) && !empty ($unid)) {
```

Comment: What is the result of your debugging tests? DB-Error? Any other Error Messages? Does the right data get sent? Does it arrive in php? ...?

Comment: `DescicaoUnid` sounds like an integer, but you default it to `''`. ?

Comment: **Warning:** You are _wide open_ to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). If you're using Wordpress, you should use their database class: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: what shall this line do? `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);` - that's a syntax error.

Comment: this `if (!empty($name)) && (!empty($unid)) { ` is obsolet, because you set them just before.

Comment: If this is all the code you have on your page, I'm not surprised you have a 500 error-message. The file does not only contain syntax errors (a closing `}` without a matching opening `{`), I also don't see where you define `$conn`.

Comment: @Jeff - In all fairness, the `empty()`-checks does make _some_ sense, since it doesn't just check if the variables exists, but if they are empty as well. What doesn't make sense is that the OP keeps executing the script regardless. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 syntax errors here

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);
```

and there

```
if ($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE);
```

So change them to

```
if ($conn->query($sql)) { // check for === TRUE is not necessary
   // either put the second query in here, or just enjoy the success
} else {
   // get the error, throw a message...
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO StockHigieneteste (DescricaoProd,DescricaoUnid) 
VALUES ('$name','$unid')";

if ($conn->query($sql1)) {
    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
} else {
    // get the error, throw a message...
}
$conn->close(); // put that OUTSIDE the condition
```

Apart from that:

It's not clear if $conn is set before somewhere.
*EDIT*: in the new code it's shown. A better approach would be to include a seperate file that does the db connection (as you might need it more often).
**You are open to sql injection attacs**!
Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

This might not be all that goes wrong, this is just the obvious things.

Comment: I made the changes as suggested but it gives the same error. I already edited the question and put the data to access the database

Comment: _"it gives the same error"_ - what error? (read my first comment)

Comment: How can I test if it arrives at php? The data is not entered into the database table. I made `var_dump ($ name);` on the php side and did not return anything

Comment: then have a look now into network tab to check what gets acutally sent. After that check what `$("#feedback_form").serialize()` gives you. ...and so on.

Comment: How do I check what $ ("# feedback_form"). Is Serialize () providing and verifying what it sends on the network tab?

Comment: I can't see where you are populating the PHP variable $query.